# How to get syntax highlighting for the embeded python within vimscript?

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting

As title, how to get syntax highlighting for the embeded python within vimscript? Is there a plugin that does syntax highlighting for embeded script?

Comment: It should work out-of-the-box. See `:h g:vimsyn_embed`

Comment: @Matt Thanks that worked!

Comment: @Matt can either turn that into an answer or OP can self-answer; let’s not leave it dangling in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the enabled embedded syntaxes in VimScript are ruled by `:h g:vimsyn_embed` variable. However, Vim and Neovim has different default settings in this regard.

In Vim's `syntax/vim.vim`:

```
" Allows users to specify the type of embedded script highlighting
" they want:  (perl/python/ruby/tcl support)
"   g:vimsyn_embed == 0   : don't embed any scripts
"   g:vimsyn_embed =~# 'l' : embed lua      (but only if vim supports it)
"   g:vimsyn_embed =~# 'm' : embed mzscheme (but only if vim supports it)
"   g:vimsyn_embed =~# 'p' : embed perl     (but only if vim supports it)
"   g:vimsyn_embed =~# 'P' : embed python   (but only if vim supports it)
"   g:vimsyn_embed =~# 'r' : embed ruby     (but only if vim supports it)
"   g:vimsyn_embed =~# 't' : embed tcl      (but only if vim supports it)
if !exists("g:vimsyn_embed")
    let g:vimsyn_embed = "lmpPr"
endif
```

However, in Neovim the last but one line is changed to `let g:vimsyn_embed = 0`

Hence, `let g:vimsyn_embed = 'P'` must be added to init.vim to enable this feature in Neovim. While in Vim it should work by default.